# Why conditionals using && is two times faster

Tags: javascript, performance

I was searching for many things today but after i found some stuff that i didn't know here at SO...so i decided to see which is the fastest this is what i have..

`&&` is two times faster than `if and condition?a:b;`

http://jsperf.com/speed-test-for-conditions

Surprising right. Or is it just my browser.

What do you think of this, do you think performance is worth it. I mean if your app starts working 2x faster. Would it be worth changing coding style to weird && s..

Comment: This is because of short-circuiting behaviour of &&, in first expression bool(undefined) = false and `false &&  anything) == false`

Comment: Your app won't start working 2x faster if your `if` conditional becomes `&&`. *That particular line of code* may be faster, but it probably won't be 2x and the difference overall will be miniscule.

Comment: i use the former anyways. you should clarify the question furthermore, because i didn't realize it til i clicked on the link

Comment: The order is reversed between Chrome and Firefox, so I wouldn't bother changing any code.

Comment: thanks for catching that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code snippets don't do the same thing. JavaScript's logical AND short-circuits, so the `(x = 'default')` part is never actually executed. Your code is interpreted like so:

```
(x == undefined) || (null && (x = 'default'))
```

Since `x == undefined` is `true`, the second part of the OR is never executed, as the whole expression will be true regardless of the boolean value of the second part.

If you add parentheses, the first and third snippets [end up being the same speed](http://jsperf.com/speed-test-for-conditions/2) (at least for me):

```
(x == undefined || null) && (x = 'default')
```

Comment: `(x == undefined || null) && (x = 'default');` this is what i think actually happens. if x equals either undefined or null then return true which causes right side to be executed that is x='de...' So as you can see it works. Try it.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: Your first example doesn't do that. Execute it and look at the value of `x`.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: Also, `x == undefined || null` doesn't check to see if `x` is either `undefined` or `null`. It first checks to see if `x == undefined`. If that's `true`, it'll return `true`. If it's `false`, `|| null` will be executed and you'll return `null`.

Comment: for what i was doing it could most likely be undefined but maybe null. But yes i also felt it was implied that i am checking for both. But i actually didn't intent to.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: You'd need to use `x===undefined||x===null` to check for both conditions. Yet, as type casting jumps in, `undefined==null`; so comparing either `x==undefined` or `x==null` will detect both `null` and `undefined`.